# From <date> to <date> OR On <date> to <date>?

Tags: prepositions, dates

I have a question about using the prepositions indicating starting and ending dates.

Which of the following is grammatically correct and why?

1. I will be away from March 1st to 5th.
2. I will be away on March 1st to 5th.

Answer (score 4):

*"I will be away from March 1st to 5th."* will be correct as you are using a time period that starts **from** March 1st and ends on another day.

For the second sentence to be correct, it should have been more like, *"I will be away on March 1st"*, implying that you are away only **on** one day.